# Symfony composer update "freeze" updating dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

With Symfony2, added the nelmio/api-doc-bundle to my composer.json. My file is like

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle" : "0.13.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.2.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "coresphere/console-bundle": "dev-master",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "2.4.5"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
```

}

But when i run composer update, the script blocks updating dependencies. Verbosing it, I can see that is this line which freezes:

```
Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$cg.json from cache
```

It was fine before I added nelmio/api-doc-bundle, but I had the same problem with another bundle (and I finally reseted the project).

---

*EDIT 02/07*: When I do a composer install (with --prefer-dist or --prefer-source), I have these errors:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



Problem 1
    - The requested package friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package jms/serializer-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.4.x-dev].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev requires jms/serializer-bundle 0.13.0 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

*EDIT 2* : I downgraded my Symfony to ~2.3, and when I do an update, the line that freezes changed

```
Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-dflydev$markdown.json from cache
```

Comment: are you sure that version 2.4.5 is compatible with your other bundles?

Comment: did you try to use prefer-source / prefer-dist ?
For more options see :

`php composer.phar install --help`

Comment: When I do a composer install instead of an update, I have these errors:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works,Try adding "minimum-stability": "dev" to composer. [google groups from phar error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion)

```
{ "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition", "license": "MIT", "type": "project", "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution", "autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" } }, "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle" : "0.13.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.2.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "coresphere/console-bundle": "dev-master",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "2.4.5" }, "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ] }, "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin" }, "minimum-stability": "dev", "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of Symfony2 some bundles are deprecated or not used anymore. You have to options:

- If you want to install your bundle and update the Symfony version to a new one change the *compose.json* file to the latest updated one and at the end append your bundle; finally run your composer.phar to update Symfony and install the bundle. Check this link for the latest json file for Symfony ([Symfony 2.4 composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/composer.json))
- If you want to install your bundle but keep all current bundles as is just append *--prefer-dist*:

  php composer update --prefer-dist